# SAML integration to Angular JS with rails back end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, single-sign-on, saml

The current scenario I am working on requires me to integrate SAML or single sign on in an Angular application having a rails back end. To start I have been able to send a request to my IdP and have received a response in the form of XML which I parse using nokogiri and I have a few credentials with which I can create the user inside the database. The problem however is I am unable to sign user in and keep them signed in once they are created.

I have **ng-token-auth** implemented on the front end and **devise_token_auth** on back end. I have used **omniauth-saml** gem to send a request to the IdP which responds with a post request and I have a seperate controller inheriting **::DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController** and having the post route where I consume the response of the IdP.

Once I have done that and the user is created inside the database I cannot figure out how to sign the user in. I do the following and I can see the sign in count incrementing on the back end but on the client side the user stays signed out.

```
@resource = User.find_or_create_user(idp_response)
if @resource.persisted?
  set_token_on_resource
  create_auth_params
  sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)
  yield @resource if block_given?
  render_data_or_redirect('deliverCredentials', @auth_params.as_json, @resource.as_json)
```

It seems like I have reached a state of a dead end for some time now. I am not sure how I can authenticate user on the front end manually as a response from my IdP. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using the headers returned in the response?

Comment: from the IdP? I get an xml file in response from which I parse and fetch a few key fields just sufficient to create a user inside my database.

Comment: since you are using `devise_token_auth`, after the @resource is created, it sends few headers in response like `Access-Token`, `Client` and others which needs to be sent with every request to let the server know that the user is signed in

Comment: I logged create_auth_params on rails console:
{:auth_token=>"***********", :client_id=>"*********", :uid=>"abc@xyz.com", :expiry=>123131312313, :config=>nil}
The network(in chrome) tab does not show any activity during the process of signing up and redirecting to my angular app.
Does that mean I may have to pass the above information manually some how?

Comment: yes, you have to store that in the session/cookie and send them as headers..by the way they are body params, can you intercept headers? that's where `access-token` and `client` comes up..

Comment: The headers I received in the response from IdP? access-token, client and other information like uid, expiry are not present inside of it.
Actually on a closer look I was able to find the request being sent in my network tab.
Also can you guide me a little about how to set cookie and emit it to the front end. This is the part that confuses me as the request to the rails api is made not by he angular client but by the IdP and the response is meant to go to the angular front end. Do i need to listen for some event globally on my front end?

Comment: unfortunately, I have no idea about idp, but in any framework the request response body should be same when you post request for sign_in e.g. `response = SomeNetworkLibrary.post({email: 'abc@xyz.com', password: '12345678'})` which when executed will return a `response` and then you can do `response.headers`, `response.body` which will be a hash, you just need to store this hash.

Comment: I just did some digging and went through the entire hash of headers I was receiving inside the request I am actually getting on my api and yes you are right the hash which I pasted above is a part of the request headers.
Having that information with me how can I log into angular application using ng-token-auth from my rails api?

Comment: once you get the hash with response code 200, you are already logged in, you just need to send these headers in consecutive requests to the rails api server. Rails will automatically validate those headers and give you access to logged in resource

Comment: I am getting the response with code 200 as well and inside the database I can see the sign in count increasing as well on the back end. If after that I redirect to for example the root path I am presented with the login page of my angular application, in angular I maybe need to change the user's state based on this response and that is something that I am confused about.

Comment: this might be helpful https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Sir I went through that as well but I am trying to achieve single sign on. The issue I come across is when I am redirected to my application after logging in from a different application I stayed logged out although the relevant entries are created in the database. 
I want to set the credentials not by submitting a form but from the request I received in my api (controller) and sign the user in to the angular application.  At the moment the problem is I dont know how to bridge this authentication flow from back to front end without form submission.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller where the sign in request is hit..

```
response = SIGN_IN_REQUEST_API
session[:api_tokens] = response.headers
```

In your `application_layout.html.haml`,

```
- if (tokens = session[:api_tokens]).present?
  :javascript
    myApp.controller('cookieController', function($scope, $resource, $http, $mdDialog, $auth, ipCookie ) {
      ipCookie('auth_headers', '{"access-token": "{token["access-token"]}","token-type": "Bearer","client": "#{token["client"]}","expiry": "#{token["expiry"]}","uid": "#{token["uid"]}"}", {path: "/",expires: 9999,expirationUnit: "days",secure: false}');
      ipCookie('currentConfigName', 'default', {path: '/',expires: 9999,expirationUnit: 'days',secure: false});
    });
  - session.delete(:api_tokens)
  %div{'ng-controller'=>'cookieController'}
```

[`Reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542808/authentication-issue-with-devise-devise-token-auth-and-ng-token-auth)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help I am trying this solution right now.

Comment: I will let you know as soon as I get it done in either case and I really appreciate all the time you spared to help me out.